# How to remove the white line under my Header react-element?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header

i don't found how i can remove the line under my custmise header build with react-native-elements library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpF85.png)

````
import {Header, Button} from "react-native-elements"
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons"
import {useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native"
import {View} from "react-native"


const Header_perso = (props) => {
 const navigation = useNavigation();
 const goTo = () => navigation.navigate(props.link);
 return(
     <View>
         <Header 
                 leftComponent= {
                <Button 
                buttonStyle={{backgroundColor:"transparent"}} 
                icon ={<Ionicons name = "arrow-back-sharp" size = {30} color = "black"/>}
                 onPress={goTo}
                />}
                 centerComponent={{ text: props.name, style: { color: 'black', fontSize:30} }}
                 containerStyle={{
                     backgroundColor:"transparent",
                     
                        
                 }}
                 
         
         />
     </View>

 )
}
export default Header_perso```
````

Comment: try to use : border: "none" on your header style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe setting bottom border to 0 could help.

```js
const Header_perso = (props) => {
 const navigation = useNavigation();
 const goTo = () => navigation.navigate(props.link);
 return(
     <View>
         <Header 
                 leftComponent= {
                <Button 
                buttonStyle={{backgroundColor:"transparent"}} 
                icon ={<Ionicons name = "arrow-back-sharp" size = {30} color = "black"/>}
                 onPress={goTo}
                />}
                 centerComponent={{ text: props.name, style: { color: 'black', fontSize:30} }}
                 containerStyle={{
                     backgroundColor:"transparent",
                     borderBottomWidth:0
                        
                 }}
                 
         
         />
     </View>

 )
}
export default Header_perso
```